# Several snap applications crashing at startup

Tags: snap, chromium, 23.04, keepassx

Several applications like KeepassXC and chromium-browser are crashing at startup. To me it looks like there is an error in snap. I had the same issue with firefox and got it fixed as soon as I took it out of snap control and replaced it with a deb package.

KeepassXC crashes with:

```
$ keepassxc
unexpected fault address 0x6de210
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x6de210 pc=0x6de210]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0x7bb445, 0x5)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72 fp=0xc00012be68 sp=0xc00012be38 pc=0x42d932
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:391 +0x455 fp=0xc00012be98 sp=0xc00012be68 pc=0x441cc5
github.com/godbus/dbus.init()
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/vendor/github.com/godbus/dbus/call.go:8 fp=0xc00012bea0 sp=0xc00012be98 pc=0x6de210
runtime.doInit(0xa406e0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5222 +0x8a fp=0xc00012bed0 sp=0xc00012bea0 pc=0x43b34a
runtime.doInit(0xa3e800)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc00012bf00 sp=0xc00012bed0 pc=0x43b317
runtime.doInit(0xa41720)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc00012bf30 sp=0xc00012bf00 pc=0x43b317
runtime.doInit(0xa3ea80)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc00012bf60 sp=0xc00012bf30 pc=0x43b317
runtime.main()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:190 +0x1da fp=0xc00012bfe0 sp=0xc00012bf60 pc=0x42f28a
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 +0x1 fp=0xc00012bfe8 sp=0xc00012bfe0 pc=0x459771
```

Chromium-browser even fails to install after I tried reinstalling it:

```
$ sudo apt install chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 48,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 105 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 chromium-browser amd64 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu3 [48,9 kB]
Fetched 48,9 kB in 0s (174 kB/s)        
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 308202 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "chromium" snap if present (run hook "configure": 
-----
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot o
pen directory "/var/lib/snapd": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot ope
n directory "/var/lib/snapd": permission denied
unexpected fault address 0x6de210
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGBUS: bus error code=0x2 addr=0x6de210 pc=0x6de210]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw(0x7bb445, 0x5)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72 fp=0xc00010de68 sp=0xc00010de38 pc=0x42d932
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:391 +0x455 fp=0xc00010de98 sp=0xc00010de68 pc=0x441cc5
github.com/godbus/dbus.init()
    /build/snapd/parts/snapd-deb/build/vendor/github.com/godbus/dbus/call.go:8 fp=0xc00010dea0 sp=0xc00010de98 pc=0x6de210
runtime.doInit(0xa406e0)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5222 +0x8a fp=0xc00010ded0 sp=0xc00010dea0 pc=0x43b34a
runtime.doInit(0xa3e800)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc00010df00 sp=0xc00010ded0 pc=0x43b317
runtime.doInit(0xa41720)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc00010df30 sp=0xc00010df00 pc=0x43b317
runtime.doInit(0xa3ea80)
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:5217 +0x57 fp=0xc00010df60 sp=0xc00010df30 pc=0x43b317
runtime.main()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/proc.go:190 +0x1da fp=0xc00010dfe0 sp=0xc00010df60 pc=0x42f28a
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 +0x1 fp=0xc00010dfe8 sp=0xc00010dfe0 pc=0x459771
-----)
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new chromium-browser package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using

```
$ uname -a
Linux 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar

$ snap version
snap    2.59.2
snapd   2.59.2
series  16
ubuntu  23.04
kernel  6.2.0-20-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

This information, might be usefull. I've encounter the same problem with a snap:
"cannot change mount namespace according to change mount ... permission denied"

I've found the problem.  It's quite odd. It's linked to AppArmor, which secures the snaps. In my Home directory in Linux I've replaced the default folder (images, music, videos, etc... ) with a symlink with the same name pointing to another drive. Looks like that was causing a security issue with AppArmor. I've removed the symlink and put back the folders, rebooted and the snap is now launching now. You can apply that solution to other snaps.